# Feffects of frequent & sudden variation in room/surrounding tempratues

Tags: physiology

If out door temprature is like 40°c with 100% humidity and indoors temperature is around 35°c. Whereas an air conditioned room in the house has  a temperature maintained at 20°c with very less humidity.
A person doing household chores moves in & out of all three temperature zones very frequently, like 3 to 5 times every ten minutes, for a total duration of say half hour.
In such a situation, what could be the physical effects on ones body?
Can it cause dizziness, sleep onset, fatigue, headache & muscular cramps, palpitations, breathing problems etc?

Comment: We cannot give medical advice or diagnoses on stack exchange. There are legal repercussions for such advice.

Comment: Rehan, you might ask this (after depersonalizing it) on Health.SE. Personal health is exactly that: personal. I'm an old lady. My dogs thrive on activity, so I go outside and chuck balls in awful heat for a few minutes, then come in to cool off, then go out again, etc., and I feel nothing untoward. That doesn't mean someone who has, say, an autonomic nervous system problem wouldn't suffer from doing that.

Comment: @John - Medical advice on Stack Exchange does not constitute a professional (doctor-patient) relationship, therefore does not constitute a legal problem. It is not technically different than the advice given on Law.se or a cooking site (if a bad answer ruins your dinner party, can you sue? I doubt it.) The problem is ethical.